# Android: synchronized() inside constructor has no effect?

Tags: java, android, constructor, synchronized

I tried searching about this problem, but didn't find anything as if I'm the only one who tried that.

Basically I have a static Object that I use to synchronize resource access inside a constructor of the containing class, and I've noticed from time to time it doesn't work!

```
private static Integer              lock = Integer.valueOf(0);

public testClass(Context ctx)
{
    if (ctx != null)
        context = ctx.getApplicationContext();
    else
        context = null;

    synchronized(lock)
    {
        Log.v(at_data.TAG, "I_AM_IN=" + I_AM_IN);
        I_AM_IN = true;

      // Access resource
      // 
      // Multiple threads do enter here!

        Log.v(at_data.TAG, "I_AM_OUT=" + I_AM_IN);
        I_AM_IN = false;
    }
}
```

I probably missed something, but didn't find any documentation saying it's not supposed to work!?.

Output:

```
I_AM_IN=false
I_AM_IN=true
I_AM_OUT=true
I_AM_OUT=false
```

Most of the time it would be this though:

```
I_AM_IN=false
I_AM_OUT=true
I_AM_IN=false
I_AM_OUT=true
```

Comment: are you sure that the multiple threads are inside synchronized block at the same time ?

Comment: Oh yes. Edited synchronized block and added output. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: I can only think that `lock` is changing. Perhaps if you set it to `final` you will find out where.

Comment: Can you please post a complete example?

Comment: Also, Integer.valueOf(0) should not be used as a lock. It's (potentially) a shared object, and if other classes do it like you do, you'll have unrelated blocks synchronized, leading to slowness (in the good case) or deadlocks (in the bad case). Simply use `new Object()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, the problem is that you're modifying the lock. You can't increment the value of an Integer object. Integer is immutable, so each time you "increment" it, you replace the lock by another lock:

```
lock = new Integer(lock.intValue() + 1);
```

Use a **final** `new Object()` as a lock, and use a separate variable to hold the count. Or use an AtomicInteger. A Semaphore might be the class you're looking for as well.

Rule of thumb: a lock should always be final. And you should never use a shared object as a lock (`Integer.valueOf(0)` is a shared object, because `valueOf(0)`, at least in some VM implementations, always return the same Integer instance).

Comment: Thanks for the last tip, Integer.valueOf was suggested by LINT for that very reason and I did a global replace ;)

Comment: By the way, being a C# dev I used Integer as locks successfully as the language/framework offered an incrementlock-type method (as far as I remember). Also C# allows overriding the ++ operator, which (unverified) should make Integer class actually mutable, as the reference/pointer stays the same, but the internal data is modified. That's what I expected of this line:
  lock++;

Answer (score 1):

[You should use a private final lock object.](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK00-J.+Use+private+final+lock+objects+to+synchronize+classes+that+may+interact+with+untrusted+code)

Comment: Why would that help? I currently use that lock as a counter to know when no more object of this class exists, so can't really use final.
Will try anyway to see if that helps, using a spare object for counting.

Comment: Nizet gives a more complete answer. Also, explicit locking yourself is very tricky, and as you can see, very easy to get wrong. You should look into Executors. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html